# "for" loop does not continue (python)

Tags: python, selenium, loops, for-loop, window

I need help with question.
my 'for' loop is not continued.

Am I missing this loop or is there something I should do to continue the loop?
The code is for extracting contacts from a website. After accessing a url, the code will open a second window. I manage to extract the code from the second window the first time, but the "for" loop does not continue. What should I do for this tie to continue? Below is the code:

```
class Extrator_olx:
    def __init__(self):
        chrome_options = Options()
        chrome_options.add_argument('--lang=pt-BR')
        chrome_options.add_argument('--disable-notifications')
        self.driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path=r'C:\Users\Daniel pc\Desktop\Tutorial chronDriver\chromedriver.exe', options=chrome_options)   
    
    def Iniciar(self):
        self.driver.get('https://mg.olx.com.br/regiao-de-juiz-de-fora/regiao-de-juiz-de-fora/autos-e-pecas/carros-vans-e-utilitarios')
        window_before = self.driver.window_handles[0]
        time.sleep(30)
       
        listado_pagina = self.driver.find_elements_by_xpath('//h2[@class="fnmrjs-10 deEIZJ"]')
        
        for lista_do_for in listado_pagina:
            self.driver.execute_script("arguments[0].click()", lista_do_for)
            self.driver.implicitly_wait(40)
            window_after = self.driver.window_handles[1]
            self.driver.switch_to_window(window_after)
            self.extrair_d_pg()
         
    def extrair_d_pg(self):      
        descricao_carro = self.driver.find_element_by_xpath('//h1[@class="sc-ifAKCX sc-1q2spfr-0 fxvTMe"]')
        preco_carro = self.driver.find_element_by_xpath('//h2[@class="sc-ifAKCX sc-1leoitd-0 buyYie"]')                
        vendedor_olx= self.driver.find_element_by_xpath('//span[@class="sc-ifAKCX sc-jhAzac sc-dYzWWc gcvYTZ sc-epGmkI hvWJHG"]')
        preco_carro_tx = preco_carro.text
        vendedor_olx_tx= vendedor_olx.text
        descricao_carro_tx = descricao_carro.text
        print(f'{descricao_carro_tx} | {preco_carro_tx} | {vendedor_olx_tx}')
        time.sleep(10)
        self.driver.close()        
        #print(preco_carro.text)
        #print(vendedor_olx.text)
        
    
curso =Extrator_olx()
curso.Iniciar()
```

Comment: Have you verified that there is anything in `listado_pagina`?

Answer (score 0):

You should avoid

```
time.sleep(x)
```

as possible !
In Selenium it would causes you some errors.
Instead you should use 'ExpectedConditions' like : presence_of_element_located (by ID ideally).

```
element = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(
    EC.presence_of_element_located((By.ID, "myDynamicElement"))
```

You will need these libraries to run this code:

```
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
```

In this case it will wait 10s until finding your element or throwing an 'TimeoutException' if the element is not found. It's an more optized way to wait for an element.
You should also avoid to click by Javascript and instead use the Selenium '.click' method.

Your variables are not well-named.
'lista_do_for' is not precise in this case. Maybe rename to 'elementOfPage' or something like that.

After you close your page and you want to came back to the original page you should re-focus this one by doing something like that :

```
self.driver.switch_to.window(self.driver.window_handles[0])
```

Also, i recommend you to read the python Selenium documentation to fully understand the framework and how it works:

https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/index.html

it will save you at certains situations.

Hope this will help you!